# How to stop laravel directory browsing

Tags: laravel

When i go to `http://localhost:3000/SahanpCMS/resources/` , it shows directory listings. how can i stop this and redirect to `404` page?

[image]

Comment: just put an index.html file or use .htaccess file

Comment: you can also add `-Indexes` to your .htaccess

Comment: actually i moved entire of public folder to root folder and changed ``index.php`` file. now i have problem with ``.htaccess`` file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `.htaccess` file to the root of your project and add the following to it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yes, that behaviour has nothing to do with Laravel, actually.

Comment: i moved all files in public folder to root folder. so i want to disallow all folders in root.