# Laravel5 shows index.php content

Tags: php, laravel, centos7

I'm new to Linux and PHP and I'm trying to access a Laravel app from another device.
Server is running a Centos and it's IP is 192.168.1.250 and my Laravel directory is /var/www/html/vls.
At first it was showing directory listing when I wen to 192.168.1.250/vls in my browser. After some search I added these lines to httpd.con:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/vls>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/vls/public"
    ServerName vls.dev
    <Directory /var/www/html/vls/>
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I go to 192.168.1.250/vls it shows index.php content as text in browser.

I even followed the solution described here:
[How to stop laravel directory browsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802196/how-to-stop-laravel-directory-browsing)

But then it showed directory listing of /public directory.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

**EDIT:**
If I make a directory and place an index.php code that includes some PHP code it works fine. But Laravel app doesn't work and shows index.php code on the browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: make sure you have `libapache2-mod-php` (or some similar name) installed

Answer (score 0):

Change your dir from `<Directory /var/www/html/vls/>` to `<Directory /var/www/html/vls/public>`

Comment: service httpd restart