# New installed Laravel app shows Exception

Tags: php, laravel, centos7

I'm trying to lunch a Laravel app. My server IP address is 192.168.1.250. After installing Laravel I tried to acess it by typing 192.168.1.250/vls. VLS is my app name in /var/www/html directory. It showed directory listing. After some search the anser in this page [How to stop laravel directory browsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802196/how-to-stop-laravel-directory-browsing) said that I should create a .htaccess file in the root of my app, it means vls directory, and put the following code in it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now it shows an exceptional:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
(1/1) NotFoundHttpException
in RouteCollection.php (line 179)
.....
```

And this is the only thing I have in /routs/web.php file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

What is wrong with it? I have not changed anything in Laravel. By the way it works fine when I use `php artisan serve --host 192.168.1.250` and I can access my app by 192.168.1.250:8000.

**EDIT:**
I added these lines to routs/web.php now it returns Hello.

```
Route::get('/vls', function () {
    return 'Hello';
});
```

It seems that Laravel considers /vls as a route parameter.

Comment: do you browse `192.168.1.250/vls/public/index.php`

Comment: No. It shows `This page isn’t working` error.

Comment: when running the command `php artisan serve --host 192.168.1.250` to start your project, the entry point for Laravel is public/index.php so I you access from browser make sure your link like 192.168.1.250/vls/public/index.php

Comment: `192.168.1.250/vls/public/index.php` does not work.

Comment: what are you using XAMPP or LAMP ?

Comment: Non. I have installed httpd service on Centos 7.

Comment: Please read the Edit.